# Converting string to a number

Tags: c

I came across this C program:

```
int main() {
    printf("Enter your address, (e.g. 51 Anzac Road) ");
    gets(address);
    number = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (address[i] != ' ') {
        number = number * 10 + (address[i] - 48);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I understand `number = number * 10 + (address[i] - 48);` is to get the number from input, but can anybody explain to me how this works? How does that produce the number from the input?

Comment: [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

Comment: Hint: `printf("%c\n", (char) 48);`

Comment: 0, but what does that help?

Comment: the way i see it is that  number which is 0 * 10, plus (address[0] in this case is 5, and minus 0), it is 5, but why do we go through all these trouble, is "48" bit of unnecessary here guys?

Comment: @YHL: Because `'3' != 3`.

Comment: Any study material still containing `gets()` and/or `main()` instead of `main(void)` is very outdated and should no longer be used as an introduction to C.

Answer (score 4):

In ASCII, the digit *characters* `'0'` through `'9'` occupy code points 48 through 57 (i hex, `0x30` through `0x39`) so, to turn a digit character into a value, you just subtract 48.

---

> As an aside, you should *really* subtract `'0'` since the standard doesn't guarantee ASCII, though it *does* guarantee that the digit characters are contiguous and ordered. C under z/OS, for example, uses EBCDIC which places the digits at code points `0xf0` through `0xf9`.

---

The loop itself is a simple shift-and-add type, to create a number from multiple digit characters. Say you have the string `"123"`, and `number` is initially zero.

You multiply `number` (zero) by ten to get zero then add digit character `'1'` (49) and subtract 48. This gives you one.

You then multiply `number` (one) by ten to get ten and add digit character `'2'` (50), again subtracting 48. This gives you twelve.

Finally, you multiply `number` (twelve) by ten to get a hundred and twenty then add digit character `'3'` (51) and subtract 48. This gives you a hundred and twenty three.

There are better ways to do this in the C standard library, `atoi` or the more robust `strtol`-type functions, all found in `stdlib.h`. The latter allow you to better detect if there was "rubbish" at the end of the number, for assistance with validation (`atoi` cannot tell the difference between `123` and `123xyzzy`).

---

And, as yet *another* aside, you should avoid `gets()` like the plague. It, like the "naked" `scanf("%s")`, is not suitable for user input, and opens your code to buffer overflow problems. In fact, unlike `scanf()`, there is *no* safe way to use `gets()`, which is undoubtedly why it has been removed from C11, the latest standard. A more robust user input function can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

There's also a large class of addresses for which that code will fail miserably, such as:

```
3/28 Tivoli Rd
57a Smith Street
Flat 2, 12 Xyzzy Lane
```

Answer (score 4):

C requires the digits `0` through `9` to be stored contiguously, in that order, in the execution character set. `48` is the ASCII value of `'0'`, so, for instance:

```
'3' - 48 == 3
```

for any digit.

ASCII is not required for C, so better is:

```
'3' - '0'
```

because while `48` is right for ASCII, `'0'` is by definition right for any character set.

If `address` contains `"456 "`, then:

- when `i == 0` and `number == 0`, `number * 10 + (address[0] - 48)` equals `0 * 10 + 4`, or `4`.
- when `i == 1`, `number * 10 + (address[1] - 48)` is `4 * 10 + 5`, or `45`.
- when `i == 2`, `number * 10 + (address[2] - 48)` is `45 * 10 + 6`, or `456`

and you're done.

Never use `gets()`, it's dangerous, and isn't even part of C anymore.